# What is the origin (or first known work) of this "Reluctant Maou Heiress" trope we see in several contemporary works?

Tags: tropes, anime-history, manga-history

This "Reluctant Demon King (魔王 Maou) Heiress" trope seems to be a subversion of the classic **"Hero vs Demons"** fantasy genre. The demon king is gone, and the heir to the throne and/or the owner of Maou's power is a female, and she has almost no interest in doing evil things to humanity. Instead, she wants to mingle with humans, helps humanity prosper and is mostly in love with the shounen main hero.

There are several anime/manga and assorted media where the heroine is:

1. Of a benevolent demeanor (not evil).
2. Heiress of, or the demon king herself.
3. Romantically involved with the MC.
4. On the run from her duties as heiress/king (see #2)
5. Strongly disinterested in pursuing the path of former demon kings.

As examples, we have:

1. [Maoyuu](http://myanimelist.net/anime/14833/Maoyuu_Maou_Yuusha)
2. [Yu-shibu](http://myanimelist.net/anime/18677/Yuusha_ni_Narenakatta_Ore_wa_Shibushibu_Shuushoku_wo_Ketsui_Shimashita.)
3. [Shinmai Maou no Testament](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23233/Shinmai_Maou_no_Testament).

Where did this trend start from?

Comment: Should I tag the question for the series mentioned? It is not about them, but about a common link between the three.

Comment: I would say no, don't tag the series used as examples (and you can't tag them all because of the 5 tags maximum).

Comment: @GaoWeiwei ok. If anyone has a better tagging, please do adjust.